# Representation of $D_{n}$ and $S_{5}$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Consider two groups : $D_{n}$ and $S_{5}$. 
For the first one let's say that $n = 2k+1$, so $|D_{2k+1}| = 4k+2$ and 
$|D_{n}/D'_{n}| = 2$. So ther will be only two one-dimensional representations, so $4k+2 = 1+1+4k$. I guess there also will be $k$ two-dimensional representations, but how can we prove it ? Even case is pretty same.

About $S_{5}$ : it's obviously that there will be $2$ one-dimensional representations and at least one four-dimensional (canonical representation $f : S_{5} \to GL_{4}$. So we have $120 = 1 + 1 + 16 + \dots$. After some logical computations we have : $120 = 1 + 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 + 64 $ and $120 = 1 + 1 + 16 + 16 + 25 + 25 + 36$. But there is only one decomposition, so one of this equalities is false. But how can we determine which one ?

Comment: You should split these into two questions.